# if Not IsEmpty not working, how to get my vba code to work

Tags: vba, excel

```
Range("A1") = "\{F11}"
Range("B1") = "TAB"
Range("C1") = "*SL1"
Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(""\"",Test!R[9]C[-1])"
Range("E1") = "^{F11}"
Range("F1") = "*SL1"
Range("G1") = "*ML(186,122)"
Range("H1") = "*SL1"
Range("I1") = "*ML(68,333)"
Range("J1") = "*AO"
Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(""\"",Test!R[9]C[-5])"
Range("L1") = "TAB"
Range("M1") = "*ML(221,199)"
Range("N1") = "*SL1"
Range("O1") = "TAB"
Range("P1") = "TAB"
Range("Q1") = "\AVL"
Range("R1") = "TAB"
Range("S1") = "*SL1"
Range("T1") = "*ML(266,190)"
Range("U1") = "TAB"
Range("W1") = "TAB"
Range("X1") = "TAB"
Range("Y1") = "TAB"
Range("Z1") = "TAB"
Range("AA1") = "TAB"
Range("AB1") = "*SL1"
Range("AC1") = "*UP"
Range("AD1") = "*UP"
Range("AE1") = "*UP"
Range("AF1") = "*SL1"
Range("AG1") = "*AA"
Range("AH1") = "\CAN"
Range("AI1") = "*SL1"
Range("AJ1") = "*SL1"
Range("AK1") = "\OTHER"
Range("AL1") = "TAB"
Range("AM1") = "*SL1"
Range("AN1") = "\Different part received"
Range("AO1") = "*AO"
Range("AP1") = "*SL1"
Range("AQ1") = "*AO"
Range("AR1") = "*ML(66,123)"
Range("AS1") = "*SL1"
```

All of the items above need to be activated IF a certain cell on another sheet is NOT blank

Sheets("Test") has data that is filtered on False from a column which returns True or False. So there could one day be 2 rows of data or 200, it is a daily changing variable. The thing I am trying to pull off is to have all of those ranges I listed above inserted on another sheet depending on the number of entries in Sheets("Test"). So if there are 200 False entries, then I am supposed to have 200 rows of the above BUT appropriately filled down. So, A1 will now be A2, then A3, etc. There are two functions that I would like to work correctly as well. They concatenate a specific cell in Sheets("Test"). So if Rows 3 and 154 are false, I would like that row to be referenced in the concatenate formula.

God I hope this makes sense. I feel like it's something simple but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
IsEmpty(Sheets("Test").Range("C1"))
```

with

```
Sheets("Test").Range("C1")=""
```

etc.

Comment: I am having more issues with the second part of that function, which is the part where it tells it to look through the column in Sheet("Test") and then paste formula in Sheet("Test2")...the IsEmpty function does what it needs to do so far

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate, this ="" trick was the only solution that worked.